# Can't display array values from a function to the main in C

Tags: arrays, c, function

```
int array[1000];
int array_size;

void * min_max_thread (void *arg)
{
  int min = array[0];
  int max = array[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < array_size; i++)
  {
    if (min > array[i])
    {
       min = array[i];
    }

    if (max < array[i])
    {
       max = array[i];
    }
  }

  int *min_max = malloc (2);
  return min_max;
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // Read array size and elements from the user
  printf ("Enter the number of elements in the array: ");
  scanf ("%d", &array_size);
  printf ("Enter the elements of the array: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
  {
    scanf ("%d", &array[i]);
  }
  pthread_t min_max_thread_id;

  // Create threads
  pthread_create (&min_max_thread_id, NULL, min_max_thread, NULL);

  // Wait for threads to finish
  void *min_max_result;
  pthread_join (min_max_thread_id, &min_max_result);

  // Print results
  int *min_max = (int *) min_max_result;
  printf ("Minimum: %d\n", min_max[0]);
  printf ("Maximum: %d\n", min_max[1]);

  return 0;
}
```

I have tried a lot of ways until someone told me to put the values in an array and use malloc to reallocate but couldn't help further, and I have never had experience with moving an array from a function to the main.

I tried adding `malloc`:

```c
int *min_max = malloc (2);
```

but it didn't work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is `array` ? where is the malloc ?

Comment: @John3136 Apologies, forgot to add the few lines and copied the old one.

Comment: `int *min_max = malloc (2);` --> `int *min_max = malloc (2 * sizeof *min_max);`

Comment: And also add `min_max[0] = min;` and `min_max[1] = max;`

Answer (score 0):

> int *min_max = malloc (2); --> int *min_max = malloc (2 * sizeof
> *min_max);
>
> min_max[0] = min;
>
> min_max[1] = max;

Thanks to @Support Ukraine